# How to update the database snapshot to match the database after changes have been made to the model

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

Using Entity FrameWork 6.1.3. and Code First.

I'm currently working in my own branch, but using a development database. Another developer has been working in the main branch and has applied some migrations to the development database after I had branched. I made some changes to some of the models in my branch by adding extra fields; the tables for these models I modified already exist on the database (apart from 1 new model).

The current snapshot in my branch is not what the actual database schema currently is. Normally I would do a `Add-Migration Merge -IgnoreChanges` to bring me up to date and then make my changes. (Correct?)

The problem is that I have changes I have made that I still need to be applied to the database and doing the above command ignores these changes. The code generated when I scaffold a new migration is trying to undo (drop/alter) all of the migrations that were applied on the main branch, and it also currently sees all of the models that I have made changes to (and some other models) as new tables and is trying to create the new tables instead of adding the new columns.

What is the best way to solve this and is it possible to avoid situations like this in the first place?

I was thinking that I could merge the main branch into my branch to get the migrations, but wasn't sure if that would solve my problem.

Any migrations generated will also need to work when applied to our production database.

Hope I've explained this well enough. I'm still quite new to EF so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common rule of thumb is: all consumers of a database that is used by Entity Framework should have 100% same version of the model snapshot, so whole migration history should 100% match for all people who connect to the database. If at least one person made any small change to the model and created a migration, he should switch to a separate database until changes are merged to the main branch, and all people have 100% same version of the model snapshot again.

Having different people make changes to model locally brings you to the situation, where a number of people have different model snapshots and try to apply their changes to model to the same database, which result in the following:

- The one who applied their changes first will have his application
  working well.
- All the rest will receive errors, saying that their local model snapshots differ from model snapshot that is stored in the database, and their migrations will fail to apply on the database.

If you use your own local database (or a remote db created just for your branch), you will not face these issues at all. The only problem you will get is inconsistent snapshot after the merge, which is simply fixed by an empty merge migration right after you do the merge from branches, that contain changes to your model.

I believe that each dev has to have its own version of the database, and your dev DB should be only used by dev application, if you host it. Otherwise you are vulnurable to breaking changes, that some other developer did to the database, and your local application - as well as remote - are broken until he fixes it.

EDIT:
I also advise to read MSDN article about using migrations in the team with CVS:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501.aspx

> Each team member should have a local development database Migrations
>   uses the __MigrationsHistory table to store what migrations have been
>   applied to the database. If you have multiple developers generating
>   different migrations while trying to target the same database (and
>   thus share a __MigrationsHistory table) migrations is going to get
>   very confused.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We do all have our own personal development databases and have started to use them. I see now it's not really optional. Is there anyway that I can recover from this? Would merging my changes into the main branch allow me to apply the correct migrations?

Comment: @T27M the cleanest way here, if you can delete the migration that you created, is to merge from main branch to yours, create your migration, and then merge it to the main branch. If you already applied your migration, you can merge to main branch and create an empty merge migration. If you can proceed development on local SQL database without merging to main, better do it that way.

Comment: I can switch to my local database to continue locally, but I did try merging from the main branch to my branch and the migration that was scaffold is still incorrect i.e as described in my question. Merging back to main would not work in this case?

Comment: @T27M yes, you have to verify, that your migration is correct before merging back to main. Did you create your migration using `-IgnoreChanges`? Did you remove your migration before re-scaffolding?

Comment: I deleted my migration (this was not applied to any database), merged main into my branch, then recreated the migration, but didn't use `-IgnoreChanges`. If I do this with `-IgnoreChanges` it gives me an empty migration, does that not mean my changes will not be applied?

Comment: @T27M this looks like a correct sequence of actions, so creating a mingration after merging to your branch should correctly take your changes into account. What migration did you get at that point?

Comment: The migration is either outdated/incorrect or when using `-IgnoreChanges` it is empty. If the other developer was to add the files I have changed to his project would he be able to apply the migration and I can then just delete my branch, and branch from main to continue my work?

Comment: @T27M if you can afford to roll back your changes, do clone from your recent changes in the branch and reapply them, that might work well (or the way you described for another dev). Also if your change is small, you can manually fix the migration you create deleting parts that you don't need and adding parts that are missing. Also after doing all these things a good thing is verify that you can apply all your migrations to a new database.

Comment: Turns out I missed a migration file that was checked into a different branch, but your steps did work with a little trail and error in between. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

What happened to me today was that I basically had the whole Migrations folder missing, so no Migration files, no Snapshot files, nothing. I wanted to do a little update on the DB (add a new column on a table). So I've followed these steps and eventually got it working (commands in Package Manager Console):

1. `Add-Migration temp` - This will generate a Migration file (which would recreate the whole database) and the Snapshot file. Apparently this Snapshot file corresponds to the current database state;
2. Deleted the Migration file, not by typing `Remove-Migration` (because this would delete the Snapshot file as well), but simply by deleting the file directly (in the Solution Explorer, for example). At this point I had the current Snapshot and no Migrations;
3. `Add-Migration new_column_etc` - By adding this migration, since I've had a Snapshot for it to compare to, it was actually well generated and was only showing the changes I did (and what I intended to update in the DB in the first place);
4. `Update-Database` - Now I have my database updated and the Snapshot file corresponds to the latest version.

I know it may deviate a bit from what was originally asked, but in desperate situations it can provide a way to re-generate the Snapshot file to the current version of the DB.